# Vim display error after installing clang

Tags: linux, vim, clang, vim-plugin, clang-complete

I wanna use clang-complete in vim.
But vim diaplay error after installing clang, image below
[image: pictures after installing clang]

I am sure the file is normal. I can read it normally before I install clang.
What should I do?

Comment: What did you type on command line?

Comment: @Harry I type `vim myfile` as usual